# How to call function when editing text inside of uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I have a login screen in my app. When the user clicks login, an api is called to check if the login credentials are correct (or not) and an error message is displayed when the login credentials are incorrect. Now the problem I'm having is after the login button is called and an error message is displayed, I want the error message to disappear when the user begins to change the text in the username/password field (UITextField). At first I tried using an event listener to try to set the alpha of the error message to 0.0 when the listener called a function. The code I used for that is down below.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textfield:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then I had an objc function for that action:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(textfield: UITextField) {
        errorLabel.alpha = 0.0
    }
```

The problem I'm having with this is the error message disappears when the user only clicks on the textfield. I only want the error message to disappear if the user actually changes the text in the textfield. How should I go about this? Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: You can use `UITextFieldDelegate`, keep a boolean and on basis of that in the delegate method `beginEditing` hide the error message.

Comment: Check if the textField.text is equal to the text that was incorrect

Comment: Yeah Leo Dabus's comment works but I have had this problem in multiple places and was wondering if there was some easier way to do this or if there was some reusable class I could make, instead of checking the input of the text field everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick version of the code

The solution is to create 2 variables which will do the work of storing the values of your credentials when they are wrong

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
 var usernameText:String? = nil
    var passwordText:String? = nil
   // we will use usernameText and PasswordText to keep track of the value of the textFields
    
    let usernameField:UITextField = {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        return textfield
    }()
    let passwordField:UITextField = {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        return textfield
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

      @objc func loginButtonTouched(){
           if we touch your login button and the credentials are wrong {
        // you will show the errorLabel
         
        ErrorLabel.alpha = 1
        // and give value to usernameText and passwordText
        usernameText = usernameField.text
        passwordText = passwordField.text
        }else{
           present(nextVC) // for example
          }
    }

 // the username and the password textField have the same action if the text change
      @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textfield: UITextField) {
        // now we will use the values we gave to usernameText and passwordText to check if one of them has changed their value
        if usernameText != usernameField.text || passwordText != passwordField.text {
            // if one of them changed their value we make disappear the errorLabel
            ErrorLabel.alpha = 0.0
        }
      }
        
      }
```